# Why is it possible that $f(x)$ has real outputs, but $\exp(\ln(f(x))$ has complex outputs?

Tags: functions, complex-numbers

This is probably a trivial question, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Say I have a function: $f(x)=x(x-6)^{1/5}$. Is the output of the function just the real numbers?

Desmos tells me yes, but my friend told me that it isn't, because $f(x)=\exp(\ln(x(x-6)^{1/5})=\exp(\ln(x)+\frac15\ln(x-6))$, and because $\ln$ of a negative number will yield a complex output, $f(x)$ should give complex answers as well.

Plotting $f(x)=\exp(\ln(x)+\frac15\ln(x-6))$, I see that it only gives real values from 6 to infinity.

Or does this mean that $x(x-6)^{1/5}$and $\exp(\ln(x)+\frac15\ln(x-6))$ are actually different functions after all?

I thought about when $(-1)^n$ is imaginary and real. When $n=0.2$, $(-1)^n=-1$ and so my function $f(x)$ should be able to handle negative $x$'s perfectly well.

However, I found that $f(x)=x(x-6)^{1/10}$ outputs real values only from 6 to infinity. This is probably because $(-1)^n$ is imaginary when $n=0.1$.

This is my question. **Why is my friend's logic sound when $f(x)=x(x-6)^{1/10}$ but it breaks down when $f(x)=x(x-6)^{1/5}$? Does it have anything to do with when $(-1)^n$ is real or is there something else about the exponential/logarithmic function that I don't know about?**

I feel like this might be in the realm of complex analysis, but I haven't studied that topic yet.

Edit: Let's say the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What is the domain of $f$? We can't talk about the range without knowing the domain of the function.

Comment: The whole real numbers. I've put in an edit.

Comment: The product to sum property of logs only works (in the reals) if both arguments are posiitve. In other words $\log(fg) \neq \log f + \log g$ if there is a place where both functions are negative. Second, $(-1)^{0.2} = -1$ is only $1$ of $5$ solutions to that equation. The others are complex valued. Generally speaking, the complex logarithm breaks the "vertical line test" i.e. each input has multiple outputs , unless you choose ahead of time which output to restrict to (like how we choose the positive square root as the convention).

Comment: Dealing with logs and exponents in the complex world is tricky because the property we take for granted all the time $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$ is not true for complex numbers.

Comment: So does that mean that for $f(x)=x(x-6)^{1/5}$, for all inputs of $x$, there is a root of unity in the reals? Whereas for $f(x)=x(x-6)^{1/10}$, from $(-\infty, 6)$, there is no root of unity that is in the reals?

Comment: If you allow the co-domain to be $\mathbb{C}$, then definitely you can consider the 5th root of $1$ . Desmos says 'yes' since it only considers the graph of $f$ in the Cartesian plane ($\mathbb{R^2}$), which means your co-domain is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Do you know why $\exp(\ln(f(x))$ does not give the same graph from -6 to infinity?

Comment: $ln(x)$ is not defined for $x \leq 0$ (non-complex)

Comment: I've not studied complex analysis, but am I correct in saying that ln(x) is defined everywhere on the complex plane except for when non-positive reals?

Comment: Yes because $Log(z) = log(|z|)+i Arg(z)$, where $z \in \mathbb{C}$-{${x \in \mathbb{R}| x \leq0}$} & I use $log$ to indicate the logarithm of the positive real number $|z|$

Comment: For the complex numbers, ln(x) is defined everywhere except at x = 0. In particular, it's defined for the negative real numbers (but the value is not real).

Comment: @SL_MathGuy There's no contradiction. As a complex logarithm, $\ln (-1) = \pi i$ because $e^{\pi i} = -1$.

Answer (score 1):

In the complex field the logarithm is a **multivalued function**, let's designate it by $Log$:
$$
Log(z) = \ln (\left| z \right|) + i\,\arg \left( z \right) + i2k\pi 
$$

When you take the *principal branch* of that function
$$
\log (z) = \ln (\left| z \right|) + i\,\arg \left( z \right)
$$
and apply it to a real $z$, you get
$$
\log (x) = \left\{ {\matrix{
   {\ln (\left| x \right|) + i\,\pi } & {x < 0}  \cr 
   {\ln (\left| x \right|)} & {0 < x}  \cr 
 } } \right.
$$

Understanding by $e^z$ the exponential function $e^{|z|} (\cos (\arg(z))+i \sin(\arg(z))$, then you have for instance
$$
\eqalign{
  &  - 1 = e^{\,\log ( - 1)}  = e^{\,0} \left( {\cos \pi  + i\sin \pi } \right) =  - 1  \cr 
  & \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,1/5}  = e^{\,\,1/5\,\log ( - 1)}  = \cos \pi /5 + i\sin \pi /5 = i^{\,2/5}  \cr} 
$$
That, keeping on the *principal branch* of the logarithm.

But $ \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,1/5} $ has five different solutions in total, which correspond to the various branches of the multivalued $Log$.
If you take the branch corresponding to $k=2$ you get
$$
\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,1/5}  = e^{\,\,1/5\,\ln 1 + 1/5i5\pi }  = e^{\,\,i\pi }  =  - 1
$$

But you do not have any branch that can provide $\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,1/10} =-1$.

The matter is that if you choose a branch of the logarithm and remain within it, then you can reverse - to a certain extent- 
the exponentiation keeping the results congruent, while if you "jump among the branches" you end with incongruencies.

Answer (score -2):

The answer (to the titular question) is simple. Whereas the equation $$e^{\log x}=x$$ is true when $x>0$ (and therefore $\log x$ is well-defined and real), it fails to be true when $x<0.$

In more detail, we provide answers to the body of your question. You say,

> Say I have a function: $f(x)=x(x-6)^{1/5}.$ Is the output of the function just the real numbers?

Yes, $f(x)$ always takes a real value whenever $x$ is real, since we can always extract *the* fifth root of any real number (which is again always real, by definition), and the product of any two real numbers is again a real number.

Then your friend's redefinition of $f(x),$ and the attendant consequences, is explained by my answer above to your titular question.

Comment: This is not completely true. By all means, every definition on the table of $\log z$ in the complex variable satisfies $e^{\log z}=z$.

Comment: In my opinion, any answer to this question should at least mention that there is no such thing as **the** logarithm for negative numbers. So before talking about wether an equation is true or false one has to clarify the meaning of $\operatorname{log}$

Comment: @BrunoKrams That's implicit in the claim that the equality $e^{\log x}=x$ fails for negative values of $x.$

Comment: @Gae.S. So you mean to say that $e^{\log(-1)}=-1,$ whatever $\log (-1)$ means anyway?

Comment: I mean that (to the best of my knowledge) whenever one defines a logarithm function/multifunction on a subset of $\Bbb C$, it is done so that it satisfies $e^{\log z}=z$ when the expression makes sense.

Comment: @Allawonder That's exactly what I'm criticizing. Judging by what the OP is asking an answer should **explicitly** mention that the crucial part in working with complex logarithms is the choice of the branch.

Comment: @Gae.S. What is $\log(-1)$?

Comment: @Allawonder A common convention is to call $\operatorname{Log}:\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}\to\Bbb C$ the function $z\mapsto(\text{ the complex number }w\text{ such that }e^w=z\land -\pi<\operatorname{Im}w\le\pi)$. Then of course $\operatorname{Log}(-1)=\frac\pi2i$. Other branches may be chosen and I agree completely with Bruno Krams.

Comment: @Gae.S. If $\log(-1)=iπ/2,$ then $$e^{\log(-1)}=e^{iπ/2}=i\ne -1,$$ as against the desired. I wonder then why you insist on claiming that the equation $e^{\log x}=x$ is always true even if $x<0.$

Comment: @BrunoKrams There's nothing to be more explicit about than it is here. The main reason why the equality fails to be true jumps out at you once you consider what happens when you allow $x$ to be negative.

Comment: @Allawonder Yeah, sorry, mistake of calculation. It should have been $\operatorname{Log}(-1)=i\pi$, as you may see by yourself from the definition I have given.